# Where are my EC2 Profile Roles (In IAM Console)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am reviewing the EC2 IAM Profile Roles and cannot locate tthem in the IAM console services > Roles. Yes these are there and selectable in the drop down menu should i want to change the IAM Role on a paritcular EC2, but I cannot find out what the Role policies are since they are simply not there in the IAM console.
Is anyone else having the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IAM Profile is effectively the glue that links an IAM Role to an Amazon EC2 instance. They can only take one role each (even though it shows as an array of Roles).

If you wish, just think of them as being the IAM Role itself. Things will magically work out that way in the console.

If you want to play with the Instance Profile, you'll need to do it through the AWS CLI or API calls.

Comment: Thanks John. That explains a lot :) 

I ran "aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name [profilename]" to locate the actual role name and I could then look this up in the IAM console where I can see the polcies. Thank you!.